# How to apply double line bottom border to a cell in iText

Tags: java, itext, border-layout

I need your help in applying the double line bottom border only to a cell and to remove the other top, right and left borders. I am able to implement the dotted line cell borders by using the below code:

```
class DoubleCell implements PdfPCellEvent {

   public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position,

      PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
      PdfContentByte canvas = canvases[PdfPTable.LINECANVAS];
      canvas.setLineDash(5f, 5f);
      canvas.rectangle(position.getLeft(), position.getBottom(),
                       position.getWidth(), position.getHeight());
      canvas.stroke();

           }
   }
```

And the PDF code is:

```
Paragraph tableParagraph = new Paragraph();
tableParagraph.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
Font total = new Font(Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 16);
PdfPCell cel3a = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Total",total));
PdfPCell cel3b = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 1",total));
cel3a.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
cel3b.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER );
cel3b.setCellEvent(new DoubleCell());
table.addCell(cel3a);
table.addCell(cel3b);
tableParagraph.add(table);
```

So please assist in applying the double line bottom border only without the other borders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are drawing a rectangle:

```
canvas.rectangle(position.getLeft(), position.getBottom(),
    position.getWidth(), position.getHeight());
canvas.stroke();
```

If you want to draw two lines, you need to draw two lines:

```
// construct first line:
canvas.moveTo(position.getLeft(), position.getBottom());
canvas.lineTo(position.getRight(), position.getBottom());
// construct second line (4 user units lower):
canvas.moveTo(position.getLeft(), position.getBottom() - 4);
canvas.lineTo(position.getRight(), position.getBottom() - 4);
// draw lines
canvas.stroke();
```

Please adapt `position.getBottom()` and `position.getBottom() - 4` if you want the lines to be at a different position. You may also want to introduce some extra padding to your cells to accommodate for the extra lines.